# on_raw_reaction_remove() can't remove role no matter what

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For some reason I keep getting a permissions error (see at bottom). Whenever I try to remove the reaction, which will remove the associated role, the permissions error occurs. This is odd, because I tripple checked that my bot role is both admin and the highest in the role list. In my bot, on_raw_reaction_add() works perfectly fine so, I have permission to add a role but not remove it?

Additionally, in my on_message() block, I have other functions that removes roles, too. So, I don't really think there is a lack of permission unless I'm doing something behind the scenes that I don't know about? Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    react_msg = message_id
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)

    if int(payload.message_id) == react_msg:

        member = await client.guilds[0].fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        
        if str(payload.emoji.name) == "\U0001f534":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Red")
        elif str(payload.emoji.name) == "\U0001f535":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Blue")
        elif str(payload.emoji.name) == "\U0001f7e2":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Green")
        elif str(payload.emoji.name) == "\U0001f7e1":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Yellow")
        elif str(payload.emoji.name) == "\U0001f7e0":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Orange")
        elif str(payload.emoji.name) == "\U0001f7e3":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = "Purple")

        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Once removing my reaction, I get:

`discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs because your bot doesn't have the correct permission in your discord server.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when your bot is either missing permissions to edit roles, or it isn't high enough on the list of your roles in your server to be able to edit and remove yours.

Any issues drop a comment